# I want to run the hello.py file in google-python-exercises in my Windows cmd terminal

Tags: python, cmd

I want to run the hello.py file in google-python-exercises in my Windows cmd terminal. Typing python is showing the exact python version which is Python 2.7.14 but typing google-python-exercises> python hello.py returns error.

Comment: please consider adding the error to your question for the sake of understanding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a python file you should be in the same directory as the file (for easiness) then type `python filename.py`. To change directories on Windows you can type `cd folder/directory` into cmd prompt.

Comment: Perhaps explicitly point out that you should not type `python` and press enter.  You need to be sitting at your `C:\users\yourself>` prompt or similar.

Comment: The suggestion worked when I put the exercise folder after changing the directory